# How to use floating number in yaml file used in Git Actions

Tags: android, yaml, github-actions

Basically I have value which is a floating number, but I am not able to perform any arithmetic operation on it.
Either I have to convert the number into integer and then use it or if any function that supports floating value.

I am not able to figure out either of the solutions

Usage:

```
      - name: Verify
        id: test
        env:
          CURRENT_COVERAGE: 35
          PREVIOUS_COVERAGE : 32.1
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=difference::$(( $PREVIOUS_COVERAGE - $CURRENT_COVERAGE))"
```

Error:

```
      syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1")
```

Comment: The thing here is that you're trying to use float number in bash, and bash doesn't handle easily float numbers natively. You may find some workarounds in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks) that you could use in your step before setting the output variable.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out the workaround @GuiFalourd

Comment: An option could be for example to create a small python script that would perform the operation, printing a value you would set on the output afterwards. For example: `run: RESULT = python myscript.py && echo "::set-output name=difference::$(echo $RESULT)"`, where the python script would manipulate the CURRENT_COVERAGE and the PREVIOUS_COVERAGE env variables after extracting them using `os.getenv("CURRENT_COVERAGE")` and `os.getenv("PREVIOUS_COVERAGE")`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way

```
diff=$(echo | awk '{print $PREVIOUS_COVERAGE - $CURRENT_COVERAGE }')
echo $diff

Output: 2.9
```